# JavaPairRDD to Dataset<Row> in SPARK

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

I have data in JavaPairRDD in format

```
JavaPairdRDD<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String,String>>>
```

I tried using below code

```
 Encoder<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String,String>>> encoder2 =
 Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.STRING()));
 Dataset<Row> userViolationsDetails = spark.createDataset(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(MY_RDD),encoder2).toDF("value1","value2");
```

But how to generate Dataset with 3 columns ??? As output of above code gives me data in 2 columns. Any pointers / suggestion ???

Comment: what do you want flatten the tuple? try `toDF("value1","value2","value3")`

Comment: @jojo_Berlini tried doing that but it gives error.

Comment: It seems that it's a bug - values in tuple should have distinguish field names. Feel free to create a Jira ticket

Comment: Thanks  @T.Gawęda for your reply, i have created Jira ticket  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24548 lets see when someone picks that up

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `printSchema` - you will see, that value2 is a complex type.

Having such information, you can write:

```
Dataset<Row> uvd = userViolationsDetails.selectExpr("value1", "value2._1 as value2", "value2._2 as value3")
```

`value2._1` means first element of a tuple inside current "value2" field. We overwrite value2 field to have one value only

Note that this will work after https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24548 is merged to master branch. Currently there is a bug in Spark and tuple is converted to struct with two fields named `value`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when tried printing schema it gave me below response: 
`
 root
 |-- value1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
`
Here value2 has same names as value, when tried to run select:

[Dataset].selectExpr("value1", "value2._1 as value2").show();
Exception what i got is "Exception :: No such struct field _1 in value, value; line 1 pos 0".

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the response. Probably some typo, I'm investigating it